# How can I create a single cookie and save multiple pairs key/values to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

In ASP.NET MVC, how can I create a single cookie and save multplie values to it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie();
cookie.Values["FirstKey"] = value1;
cookie.Values["SecondKey"] = value2;
```

or a shortcut:

```
cookie["ThirdKey"] = value3;
```

HttpCookie.Values is a NameValueCollection, a class that appears in many places in ASP.NET MVC.  Read [this](http://dotnetperls.com/namevaluecollection) for a good tutorial on how to use it to its full potential.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be rephrased as: "How can I store multiple values in a single string?"

It's up to you to come up with a system. If the values are simples numbers or strings, use a separator like a ";" and then split later.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.cookie = "myCookie=myValue";
document.cookie = "myOtherCookie=myOtherValue";
```